# iam trying to make an YT api but all i get is this error everytime: No such file or directory: 'client_secrets_file.json'

Tags: python, api, youtube, youtube-data-api

here is where i got the code from https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22statistics%22%5D%2C%22id%22%3A%5B%22dQw4w9WgXcQ%22%5D%7D&apix=true

here is my code (its basicaly the same):

```
import os

import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors
import json

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"]

def main():

    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"



    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "client_secrets_file.json"


    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    request = youtube.videos().list(
        part="statistics",
        id="dQw4w9WgXcQ"
    )
    response = request.execute()

    print(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

this is the error to be excact:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\m8\Desktop\ffs\cockclcosks.py", line 37, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\m8\Desktop\ffs\cockclcosks.py", line 22, in main
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
  File "C:\Users\m8\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google_auth_oauthlib\flow.py", line 203, in from_client_secrets_file
    with open(client_secrets_file, "r" ) as json_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'client_secrets_file.json'
```

here is flow .py:

199

```
   Returns:
        Flow: The constructed Flow instance.
    """
   with open(client_secrets_file, "r" ) as json_file:
        client_config = json.load(json_file)

   return cls.from_client_config(client_config, scopes=scopes, **kwargs)
```

208

any thoughts? i am very much a beginner so it is probably something rather stupid that i dont know of

so if anyone knows what is the problem, i'd give you a big kiss on the forehead

Comment: *No such file or directory* - It's trying to load the mentioned file. Is the file there or not?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have *client_secrets_file.json* at the root of your project.

Comment: oooooooh, thank you dude, but im not quite sure i know what "root" means, is it just like (C:) or (D:)?

Comment: It's the place where your .py with the main function is located in your file system.